What is inside of a typical RF transformer?
I am tempted to decap this 500 MHz transformer, but guessing the internals are typical and well-known by experts here.
I don't understand why many companies don't even spec the two windings' DC resistance and low-frequency (e.g., 1 MHz) inductance in their datasheets.  How can I estimate these?
I suspect the coils are thin (like AWG 40) wires wound on a toroidal (or binocular, but not a simple bobbin/rod) ferrite core, but I can really only infer the turns ratio from the datasheet, not the exact number of turns, right?  Are the windings typically bifilar (i.e., alongside each other) throughout the entire toroid, or separated such that the primary is on one side of the toroid and the secondary is on the other side of the toroid (this would help me estimate parasitic capacitances)?

For "symmetry", windings are typically bifilar or multifilar.

They make RF transformers that don't have a cover over them, so you could look at some of those. The covered ones will be the same sort of thing but with a bit of plastic or ceramic around them.
There are a couple of pictures of some in this article on RF transformer fundamentals. You can do a Google image search to find more, there are a number of ways they are made, both with toroidal and binocular cores. There is also this app note on how RF transformers work and how they are measured, so those two documents might be of some help to you.

Thanks, that helps!  Any idea on how I would know whether there are 5 turns inside, or 10, or more, or some way to estimate the winding inductance for the datasheet I linked (which is useful if I'm not in a standard 50 ohm system)?

@bobuhito  You might try contacting the manufacturer to see if they can provide you more info than what's in the datasheet.

if bifilar you could possibly guess turns count by measuring the inter-winding capacitance
